# C#: FileStream.Read() doesn't read the file up to the end, but returns 0

Tags: c#, filestream

Here is how i do it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string FileName = "c:\\error.txt";
    long FilePosition = 137647;

    FileStream fr = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open);
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    string data = string.Empty;
    fr.Seek(FilePosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

    while (fr.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
    {
        data += encoding.GetString(b);
    }
    fr.Close();
    string[] str = data.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (string s in str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The str array ends with these lines:

> ***** History for hand T5-2847880-18 (TOURNAMENT: S-976-46079) *****
>   Start hand: Tue Aug 11 18:14

but there are more lines in the file.

I've uploaded error.txt to sendspace: http://www.sendspace.com/file/5vgjtn
And here is the full console output: the_same_site/file/k05x3a

Please help! I'm really clueless here.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code has some subtle errors and problems in:

- You assume that the whole buffer has been filled by calling `GetString(b)`
- You assume that each buffer ends at the end of a character. Use a `TextReader` (e.g. `StreamReader`) to read text data, avoiding this sort of problem.
- You're not closing the file if an exception occurs (use a `using` directive)
- You're using string concatenation in a loop: prefer `StringBuilder`

As others have pointed out, [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) would avoid a lot of this work. There's also [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx), and [`TextReader.ReadToEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readtoend.aspx) for non-files.

Finally, just use `Encoding.UTF8` instead of creating a new instance unless you really need to tweak some options.

Comment: Thank you very much for so detailed answer!
File.ReadAllLines doesn't fit me because the file can grow very large and a lot of processing required to find the line that I need.
Creating a StreamReader from a FileStream is just what I looked for.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

Not technically an answer to your question, but you could replace all that with:

```
string[] str = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\error.txt");
```

**Edit (as promised):**
Rather than missing a piece, it seems to me that you will have a duplicate of the last part. You're not reading a full 1024 bytes from the file, but you are turning all 1024 bytes into a string and appending it.

Your loop should be like this instead:

```
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = fr.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0)
{
    data += encoding.GetString(b, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Other than that: what Jon said :)

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you make your life easier and do this?

```
string[] str = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\\error.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find it significantly easier to simply use File.ReadLines().  Skip the lines you don't care about, instead of using the position.

```
int counter = 0;
foreach (string s in File.ReadAllLines(FileName))
{
    ++counter;
    if (counter > 50?)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

You could also use the StreamReader, which lets you wrap the stream after setting its position, then use the ReadLine() method.

Comment: Supposedly he stored that byte position the previous time he read the file, and now he just wants to read the part that's new. Using the file position would be preferable in that case. Of course, you need to be sure that the file doesn't get overwritten in the meantime (a log being cycled for example).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but check this:

```
public void StreamBuffer(Stream sourceStream, Stream destinationStream, int buffer = 4096)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        sourceStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        var memoryBuffer = memoryStream.GetBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < memoryBuffer.Length;)
        {
            var networkBuffer = new byte[buffer];
            for (int j = 0; j < networkBuffer.Length && i < memoryBuffer.Length; j++)
            {
                networkBuffer[j] = memoryBuffer[i];
                i++;
            }
            destinationStream.Write(networkBuffer, 0, networkBuffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

...and keep in mind that memory streams are great and guaranteed to get you a byte array from a stream to be used in other ways. Use it.